# Check for bool in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following jQuery (I've got it wrapped in the document ready function and all that, so please know I'm just showing you the inside of the function.

```
..
            var itemIsSold = $("#itemIsSold").val();
            alert(itemIsSold);
            if(!itemIsSold) {
               ...
    }
```

where itemIsSold is a hidden input field.  I get the value False upper case F when it hits the alert but never enters my next if statement.  I know this has to be something stupid simple.

Comment: Is there any way to check it as an actual bool?  I'm trying to grab a bool property from my asp.net code-behind and right now I am putting that value into an input field but there's got to be a better way to grab it from JS other than a hidden field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the input's value contains the string "False", that will not translate into a false boolean value. You will need to actually check for `itemIsSold == "False"`.

Answer (score 4):

Since the value of the hidden input field is a string, `!"False"` will be evaluated to *false*. Note that any string other than a string with the length of 0 is treated as *true*. So you should rather compare the string value to another string value like `"False"`:

```
if (itemIsSold == "False") {
    // …
}
```